# a[b,c] notation, what does it mean?

Tags: notation

I am reading the paper titled ["A Theory for Record Linkage"](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse590q/04au/papers/Felligi69.pdf) by Pellegi & Stunter, where they present the following definition:

$$ \gamma [ \alpha (a), \beta (b)]=\{ \gamma ^{1}[ \alpha (a),  \beta (b)],\ .\ .\ .\ ,  \gamma^{k}[ \alpha (a),  \beta (b)]\} $$

I understand $ f(x,y) $ which we're all familiar with, but what is $ f[x,y] $ ?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the author is trying to comply with a rule that states you should avoid nested parenthesis, so he just uses brackets insted of double parenthesis but the meaning is the same.

Answer (score 1):

By having a fast read of the linked paper i think $f[x,y]$ indicates a scalar function having as independent variables the two records $\alpha$ and $\beta$ that are functions of $a$ and $b$

Answer (score 1):

Immediately before the definition, the paper introduces it by:
"Formally we define the comparison vector as a vector function of the records $\alpha(a), \beta(b)$:"  Prior to that, $a$ is identified as a generic element of a set $A$ and likewise $b\in B$, and finally (but verbosely) we are told that $\gamma : A\times B \rightarrow \Gamma$, where $\Gamma$ is the set of all realisations of $\gamma$ and called the *comparison space*.

It is a little odd for a vector to be given using brace-notation (i.e. $\gamma = \{\cdots \}$) and later on the paper $\gamma$ is referred to as $\gamma = (\gamma^1, \gamma^2, \ldots \gamma^K)$  There are similar inconsistencies with probabilities, where we see both $P(a,b)$ and $P\{\gamma [\alpha(a), \beta(b)] \}$ written but it does appear as though the author is attempting to use parentheses/brackets/braces to distinguish between scalar and vector quantities.  The paper dates from 1969 when notational standards were slightly different.

You may safely interpret $\gamma[\alpha(a), \beta(b)]$ as $\gamma (\alpha(a), \beta(b))$, though you might, if you're writing things down yourself, need sometimes to clarify that something is a vector operation, or is performed component-wise, rather than being a scalar operation.